# looking for records with specific property values

Tags: xml, postgresql, pgadmin-4, blackboard

I am trying to add a feature to this query that will allow me to display or search by the properties contained in the extended_data column listed below.  the property is 'custom:institutionid'.

What do I have to add to this query to search this property for a specific string.  That string is 'ottawa2'.

```
select cm.course_id, encode(cc.extended_data::bytea,'escape'), cc.title, cc.cnthndlr_handle

    from course_contents as cc
    
    inner join course_main as cm
    on cc.crsmain_pk1 = cm.pk1
    
    where cm.course_id like '%BUS-7700-SU-2020-%'
    and cc.cnthndlr_handle = 'resource/x-bbgs-partner-cloud'

    and (cc.title ilike '%MyLab%'
         or cc.title ilike '%Pearson%')
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the response.  I figured it out. Posting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, I didnt realize the extended_data column was just text.

Thank you!

```
select cm.course_id, encode(cc.extended_data::bytea,'escape'), cc.title

    from course_contents as cc
    
    inner join course_main as cm
    on cc.crsmain_pk1 = cm.pk1
    
    where  cc.extended_data like '%ottawa2%'
```